# Display dots when text is too long, but allow multilines

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I'm working on component in which it needs to show three dots when text inside box is longer than height of box. What I managed to do is to hide the text that goes bellow box, but it doesn't show me three dots, it only cuts the text.

This is my snippet:

```
 <div className={styles.box} key={index}>
            <img src={boxDataItem.boxPictureLink} alt='photo'></img>
            <button
              className={styles.boxTitleButton}
              onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(boxDataItem.boxTitleLink, event)}>{boxDataItem.boxTitle}</button>
          </div>
```

Css:

```
.placeholder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;

  .box {
    border-top: 8px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 115px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .boxTitleButton {
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'ApexSerif-Book';
    letter-spacing: 2;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px !important;
    max-height: 125px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }

  .boxTitleButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Any help how to achieve that would be appreciated

Comment: if you change <button> to <div> it works alright.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example:

HTML

```
<div class="test" >
     
       this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dix    this is my dixscgsdf ghsf dh sfg hsfg h dfg hdfghj 
          </div>
```

CSS

```
  .test {
  display:block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 300px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;height:300px;min-height:300px;
 

  }
```

The apply it to your code and it should work